# Swift/iOS - Sharing Model State between View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, architecture

I have a question regarding sharing a model's state between View Controllers.

Let's take an example: the Twitter app. In the timeline feed, you see a list of statuses, which are loaded from the API, serialised as models. And in the mentions feed, you also have a list of Statuses. They also are loaded from the API, serialised as models, but as different instances. If a user taps the heart button on the mentions feed, it should show up as a liked tweet in the timeline feed as well. But that means sharing the state of two different model instances that represent the same status update.

The approach I'd take to solve this inconsistent state is use a "cache" of Statuses. I'd put it in the Status model as a static property, like so:

`static var cache: Array<Status> = Array<Status>()`

and use helper methods to always use a single instance for each post, no matter from what view controller they are loaded/modified.

Is that anti-pattern? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Do you use Core Data? Then there is an easy solution.

Comment: @Andreas In this example and in my case, no. I just load data from the API and storing it doesn't make much sense, given the time sensitive nature of tweets and status updates (in my case). Out of curiosity, how would Core Data solve this?

Comment: In CoreData you have: NSFetchedResultsController + NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate. Then you get notified about any changes made to objects.

Comment: Are you using the Twitter API? Building a Twitter-like app? You mention that "If a user taps the heart button on the mentions feed, it should show up as a liked tweet in the timeline feed as well." Are you calling an API to update the liked tweet, or is that "like" lost when the user restarts their phone or the app is force quit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to rephrase first.

- Get API A returns arrayA[ X, Y, Z]
- Get API B returns arrayB[M, Y, F]
- View controller A shows array A
- View controller B shows array B
- Objects are not persisted

User modifies Y in View controller A, but view controller B does not show update.

- Option 1: Put all objects into one array and add a mechanism to know
  which should be displayed in A and B view controllers
- Option 2: When update in either array occurs, update other array if
  element exists
- Option 3: Get API A and Get API B handlers store results in arrayC or
  dictionaryC, but also maintain arrayA and arrayB.  However A and B no
  longer hold instances of objects, rather references to the objects in
  arrayC or dictionaryC.  This is really just an implementation of
  option 1.  I'd got with a dictionaryC where key is the uuid of the object stored in value, and array A & B just store keys.

Sure there are other options, like sending a notification so other view controller knows to refresh data.

I don't think you should go down the road of keeping different instances in sync though.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken Twitter use Firebase, so autoupdating is just thanks to live observing of database. You should probably think about observing changes in your objects and update collections that your views are basing on appropriately. I don't know your exact architecture though.